# Module parse failed: Unexpected token - react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I built a react component package locally, with Rollup.

Tech stack of package is: React, typescript, styled-components and so on...

1. That package lives inside of the one project.
2. Now I am trying to use that package inside of another project locally.
3. Now I am trying to test that package

   - yarn link
   - open second project executed yarn link "package-name"
   - Imprted component (package)
   - yarn start

Result:

```
Failed to compile.

../enrollment-client/src/components/GeneralSectionForm/GeneralSectionForm.tsx 31:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (31:7)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import { TOAST_ERRORS } from '../../utils/constants';
| 
> export type QuestionElementRef = {
|   id: string | undefined;
|   element: HTMLDivElement | null;
```

got the error regarding that the current webpack configuration inside of the project is not enough to compile this package - something like that.

That is something that I am currently investigating, and trying to figure out why? :)

Any help will be super appreciated

Comment: Same happening to me, did you find out what was the problem?

Comment: I also have the very same problem... Any advices?

Answer (score -1):

I also got the same error message and was stuck.
My project looks like the following example.

```
/cra-project // Frontend UI project(not monorepo root)
 |- /node_modules
 |- /packages
 | |- /value-objects // Local package
 |   |- /src
 |   |  |- index.ts
 |   |  |- ...
 |   |- packages.json
 |- /src
 |  |- index.ts
 |  |- ...
 |- packages.json
 |- tsconfig.json
 |- yarn.lock
```

The *value-objects* package was added as symlink to `node_modules` with `yarn add link:./packages/value-objects`.

But exec `yarn add ./packages/value-objects` and copied to the same location did not solve the problem.

So I don't consider this problem (taking the error message seriously) to be caused by react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader.

I honestly don't know if this is an adequate answer, but why don't you try compiling the *enrollment-client* package individually?

Doesn't work?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31224972)